# How to add an ID to an existing HTML element?

Tags: html

I'm using the Press Customizr theme. I need to add an ID (not class) to an existing HTML element from the theme (specifically it's the Related posts section)

Is there a way I can do this with a filter/hook? The element has an existing class, so if I could target that element via its class and add a unique ID to it, without removing the class.

Comment: There is no filter for arbitrarily changing HTML elements. There can't be. You will need to check with the theme documentation and author to see if there's something in your theme that will let you do this.

Comment: Well in that case the only solution would be to add an empty html element right next to the one I want to target. Is that possible? How do I add a new element while using "right after X element" as its location?

Comment: You can’t do that either. Everything you’re asking would require support from the theme.

Comment: So you know, technically yes you can do that with JavaScript, i.e. jQuery('.the-existing-class').attr( 'id', 'the-id-you-want' ). However you can't be sure there aren't multiple elements with that class, and the code would apply to all of them unless you limited it. It's still a backwards way of thinking though. Adding something to the DOM like this should be done before the page is given to the browser, which is in the realm of the theme.